# Select2 not working inside foreach loop and retaining its orginal width

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am trying to repopulate multi-select select2 dropdown inside foreach loop in js which actually worked for repopulating select2 but failed in retaining its original width and selected values. Below is my code so please anyone who will help I will be thankful. thank you

```
select2Load=function(data){
            $.each($(".ClassName"), function (index, value) {
                var selectedValue = $(value).val();
                var id = '#' + value.id;
                $(id).html('').select2({
                    data: data,
                    placeholder: 'Select',

                });


                if (selectedValue.length > 0) {

                    $(id).select2('val', selectedValue);
                } else {
                    $(id).select2({
                        width:'100%',
                       placeholder: 'Select'
                    })
                }
                $(id).parent().find('.select2-container').css("width", "100%");


            });

        }
```